# multicolumn with stacked spacing

Tags: tabularx, overleaf

I am trying to align these three columns for my resume to be consistent (one column to the left, next centered, other to the right). But the result is not what I want and I wanted to ask how I can fix it.

here is my current function (modified from the modernstlyebanking.sty of the cventry function):

```
  \newcommand*{\certentry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcr{}}%
      {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} & { #2} \\%
      
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

and my entries are:

```
\certentry{2022}{}{Applied Machine Learning}{University of Michigan}{\textit{}}{}

\certentry{2015}{}{Business Management of Technology}{Georgia Institute of Technology}{\textit{}}{}
```

but it produces this:
[image]

when ideally, I would like it to look like this:
[image]

Comment: Please compose from your code fragment complete small document with your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You not provide an MWE, so we haven't any information about used  documentclass page layout.
- Why your definition of `\certentry` is so complex. Does it has some other purposes beside write text lines shown in image?
- I guess, that desired result can be obtained by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand*{\certentry}[3]{\noindent%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} XXr @{}}%
  \textbf{#1}   &   \textbf{#2} &   #3      
  \end{tabularx}            }

\begin{document}
\certentry{Applied Machine Learning}{University of Michigan}{2022}
\certentry{Business Management of Technology}{Georgia Institute of Technology}{2015}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shoe part of page layout)

Comment: That did it! Thanks!